# Why is the move constructor called from the default one when it is passed to async?

Tags: c++

i have a class like this:

```
class move_only
{
public:
    int valut;
    move_only() {}
    move_only(move_only&&);
    void operator()();
};

move_only::move_only(move_only&&)
{
    cout << "here";
}

void move_only::operator()()
{
}
```

i wonder why when you call:

```
auto flow = std::async(move_only());
```

first called

```
move_only()
```

(which is understandable), but why then:

```
move_only(move_only&&);
```

and only then

```
void move_only::operator()
```

I will be glad to help, thank

Comment: Lots of info here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async but basically it need to copy/move the parameters in case they go out of scope before the async call completes.

Comment: Further `auto flow = std::async(move_only());` will create a rvalue instance of `move_only` which gets destroyed at the `;`  If not copied/moved by `std::async` the call would be left dangling if for instance  `std::async` only took a reference to the parameter.

Comment: What did you expect would happen (and why)?

Comment: @JaMiT I thought that at first :move_only()  to create an object,and then void operator()();
I just started learning async and don't really understand how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backtrace of gcc 10.2 at the moment the move constructor is invoked:

> 1 move_only::move_only
> 2 std::_Head_base<0ul, move_only, false>::_Head_base<move_only>
> 3 std::_Tuple_impl<0ul, move_only>::_Tuple_impl<move_only>
> 4 std::tuple<move_only>::tuple<move_only, true, true>
> 5 std::thread::__make_invoker<move_only>
> 6 std::async<move_only>
> 7 std::async<move_only>
> 8 main

Please note how `move_only`, the name of your class, is smoothly transferred 6 levels of indirection to the point where it is really needed!

Let's work this backtrace out, in reverse order:

1. `main` calls `async` - that's what we can see. The rest the *implementation*
2. `async` calls itself with a proper execution policy explicitly given as an argument
3. `async` is a friend to `future` and calls `__future_base::_S_make_async_state` to create  a `__state`, which is a shared pointer that will be used by `async` to create a `future`. We don't see `_S_make_async_state` - it is a trivial function and perhaps gcc has inlined it even in Debug miode, this is a bit weird.
4. The first argument  of `_S_make_async_state` is  of type `std::tuple`. It is generated by `std::thread::__make_invoker`
5. `std::tuple` inherits publicly from `_Tuple_impl`
6. `_Tuple_impl` inherits privately from `_Head_base`
7. `_Head_base` has a data member `_M_head_impl`, of type `_Head`:

```
   _Head _M_head_impl;
```

Please notice that apparently this member is embedded "by value" - we can see no evidence of pointer, `*`, reference, '`&`, etc. But this is C++, these might be hidden in the definition of `_Head`. But when we look at the backtrace, we can identify `_Head` with your class name, `move_only`. Hurray!

This data member is constructed in this line:

```
_M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__h))
```

Here, `std::forward` provides the perfect forwarding of your function or function object: if you use an r-value as the argument, the constructor of `_Head_base` will have this information passed all the way from your `main`. No references, no pointers - the member will be constructed by value. But since it is being constructed from a temporary object and the move constructor is available, the move constructor will be used here. The mystery is solved.

The really big question is this: is this call to move constructor guaranteed by the standard or is it an implementation "detail"? Since C++ sports a feature like guaranteed or just optional copy elision, one should write the constructors in such a way that they have no side effects and it should not matter whether an object is copied, moved or "copy-elised".

The next question: how can I guess, given the signature of `std::async`, that the function object will be copied, moved or passed by reference?
Let's see:

```
std::future<std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Function>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>>
    async( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

This may be confusing at first, for clearly, without doubt, `std::async` accepts all its parameters *by reference* and no move constructor can be called *here*. But can it be called elsewhere?

One hint is *perfect forwarding* seen in `&&` applied to arguments with a type deduced from a template parameter.  In particular, `f` is being passed by perfect forwarding. If anyone uses perfect forwarding, they want to keep the information whether the argument is an l- or r-value, so be prepared for invocation of a copy or move constructor *somewhere*. The second hint is purely logical. `std::async` is supposed to be rock-solid, **safe** means of using multithreading. If it is to be safe, it must do literally everything to obtain all its arguments by value. If they were passed by reference or pointer, the parameters passed to a function called asynchronously may cease to exist long before this function returns. In this case the function parameter would at some point of time turn into rubbish and the function would have no clue as to when. So, you should expect that by default all arguments to `std::async` are effectively (and perhaps *indirectly*) passed by value, and keep your fingers crossed that the implementation is so smart that it can actually move them whenever it is legitimate to do so.

Comment: thank you for your work, I will carefully analyze your answer :)